# Embed every video in a directory on webhost

Tags: html, video, embed

This may sound silly... but is there any way to embed all videos in a directory to a webpage? I'm hosting some videos on my website but right now you have to manually browse the directory and just click a link to a video.

I know I can just embed those videos to a html page but is there any way to make it adapt automatically when I add new videos?

Answer (score 0):

How you do this will depend on how you are building your server code and web page code, but the example below which is node and angular based does exactly what you are asking:

```js
// GET: route to return list of upload videos 
router.get('/video_list', function(req, res) {
    //Log the request details
    console.log(req.body);

    // Get the path for the uploaded_video directory 
    var _p;
    _p = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'uploaded_videos');

    //Find all the files in the diectory and add to a JSON list to return
    var resp = [];
    fs.readdir(_p, function(err, list) {
        //Check if the list is undefined or empty first and if so just return 
        if ( typeof list == 'undefined' || !list ) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            // For each file in the directory add an id and filename to the response
            resp.push( 
                {"index": i,
                "file_name": list[i]}
            );
        }

        // Set the response to be sent
        res.json(resp);
    });
});
```

This code is old in web years (i.e. about 3 years old) so the way node handles routes etc is likely different now but the concepts remains the same, regardless of language:

- go to the video directory
- get the lit of video files in it
- build them into a JSON response and send them to the browser
- browser extracts and displays the list

The browser code corresponding to the above server code in this case is:

```js
$scope.videoList = [];

    // Get the video list from the Colab Server
    GetUploadedVideosFactory.getVideoList().then(function(data) {

        // Note: should really do some type checking etc here on the returned value
        console.dir(data.data);

        $scope.videoList = data.data;
    });
```

You may find some way to automatically generate a web page index from a directory, but the type of approach above will likely give you more control - you can exclude certain file names types etc quite easily, for example.

The full source is available here: https://github.com/mickod/ColabServer